# Mono output when using X3DAudio

Tags: c++, xaudio2

I'm making a simple audio engine, the audio works well in 2D, now I want to use X3DAudio to have a sound that is positioned in 3D space. I've followed the docs and now can play sound using X3DAudio but for some reason, it's outputting mono sound although my master has 2 channels and the sound also has 2 channels.
What I'm doing wrong?

First, I initialize X3DAudio:

```
DWORD dwChannelMask;
pMasteringVoice->GetChannelMask(&dwChannelMask);

X3DAudioInitialize(dwChannelMask, X3DAUDIO_SPEED_OF_SOUND, hX3dAudio);
```

Then, I initialize listener stuff (and convert vectors from my coordinate system to coordinate system X3DAudio uses):

```
x3dAudioListener.pCone = NULL;

listenerProps.position = X3DAUDIO_VECTOR(-listenerProps.position.x, listenerProps.position.z, listenerProps.position.y);
listenerProps.velocity = X3DAUDIO_VECTOR(-listenerProps.velocity.x, listenerProps.velocity.z, listenerProps.velocity.y);
listenerProps.topVector = X3DAUDIO_VECTOR(-listenerProps.topVector.x, listenerProps.topVector.z, listenerProps.topVector.y);
listenerProps.forwardVector = X3DAUDIO_VECTOR(-listenerProps.forwardVector.x, listenerProps.forwardVector.z, listenerProps.forwardVector.y);

x3dAudioListener.OrientFront = listenerProps.forwardVector;
x3dAudioListener.OrientTop = listenerProps.topVector;
x3dAudioListener.Position = listenerProps.position;
x3dAudioListener.Velocity = listenerProps.velocity;
```

Then, I initialize DSP settings:

```
XAUDIO2_VOICE_DETAILS masterVoiceDetails;
pAudioEngine->pMasteringVoice->GetVoiceDetails(&masterVoiceDetails);

XAUDIO2_VOICE_DETAILS sourceVoiceDetails;
pSourceVoice->GetVoiceDetails(&sourceVoiceDetails);

p3dAudioMatrix = new float[sourceVoiceDetails.InputChannels * masterVoiceDetails.InputChannels];
memset(p3dAudioMatrix, 0, sizeof(float) * sourceVoiceDetails.InputChannels * masterVoiceDetails.InputChannels);

x3dAudioDSPSettings.SrcChannelCount = sourceVoiceDetails.InputChannels;
x3dAudioDSPSettings.DstChannelCount = masterVoiceDetails.InputChannels;
x3dAudioDSPSettings.pMatrixCoefficients = p3dAudioMatrix;
x3dAudioDSPSettings.pDelayTimes = NULL;
```

And then apply the sound position:

```
emitterProps.position = X3DAUDIO_VECTOR(-emitterProps.position.x, emitterProps.position.z, emitterProps.position.y);
emitterProps.velocity = X3DAUDIO_VECTOR(-emitterProps.velocity.x, emitterProps.velocity.z, emitterProps.velocity.y);
emitterProps.topVector = X3DAUDIO_VECTOR(-emitterProps.topVector.x, emitterProps.topVector.z, emitterProps.topVector.y);
emitterProps.forwardVector = X3DAUDIO_VECTOR(-emitterProps.forwardVector.x, emitterProps.forwardVector.z, emitterProps.forwardVector.y);

x3dAudioEmitter = {0};
x3dAudioEmitter.pCone = NULL;
x3dAudioEmitter.pLFECurve = NULL;
x3dAudioEmitter.pLPFDirectCurve = NULL;
x3dAudioEmitter.pLPFReverbCurve = NULL;
x3dAudioEmitter.pVolumeCurve = NULL;
x3dAudioEmitter.pReverbCurve = NULL;
x3dAudioEmitter.OrientFront = emitterProps.forwardVector;
x3dAudioEmitter.OrientTop = emitterProps.topVector;
x3dAudioEmitter.Position = emitterProps.position;
x3dAudioEmitter.Velocity = emitterProps.velocity;
x3dAudioEmitter.InnerRadius = 2.0f;
x3dAudioEmitter.InnerRadiusAngle = X3DAUDIO_PI/4.0f;
x3dAudioEmitter.ChannelCount = soundInfo.iChannels;
x3dAudioEmitter.ChannelRadius = 10.0f;
x3dAudioEmitter.CurveDistanceScaler = 1.0f;
x3dAudioEmitter.DopplerScaler = 1.0f;
float* pEmitterAzimuths = new float[x3dAudioEmitter.ChannelCount];
memset(pEmitterAzimuths, 0, x3dAudioEmitter.ChannelCount * sizeof(float));
x3dAudioEmitter.pChannelAzimuths = pEmitterAzimuths;


UINT32 iFlags = X3DAUDIO_CALCULATE_MATRIX;
if (bCalcDopplerEffect) iFlags |= X3DAUDIO_CALCULATE_DOPPLER;


X3DAudioCalculate(pAudioEngine->hX3dAudio, &pAudioEngine->x3dAudioListener, &x3dAudioEmitter, iFlags, &x3dAudioDSPSettings);

XAUDIO2_VOICE_DETAILS masterVoiceDetails;
pAudioEngine->pMasteringVoice->GetVoiceDetails(&masterVoiceDetails);

delete[] pEmitterAzimuths;

HRESULT hr = pSourceVoice->SetOutputMatrix(pAudioEngine->pMasteringVoice, soundInfo.iChannels, masterVoiceDetails.InputChannels, x3dAudioDSPSettings.pMatrixCoefficients);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    // error handling
}

if (bCalcDopplerEffect)
{
    hr = pSourceVoice->SetFrequencyRatio(x3dAudioDSPSettings.DopplerFactor);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        // error handling
    }
}
```

The debug layer is enabled and I see no errors. I've checked `soundInfo.iChannels` is == 2 and master channel count is also 2.
I apply listener/emitter properties like this:

```
listenerProps.position = X3DAUDIO_VECTOR(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
listenerProps.velocity = X3DAUDIO_VECTOR(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
listenerProps.forwardVector = X3DAUDIO_VECTOR(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
listenerProps.topVector = X3DAUDIO_VECTOR(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

SEmitterProps props;
props.position = X3DAUDIO_VECTOR(-5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
props.velocity = X3DAUDIO_VECTOR(fSoundSpeed, 0.0f, 0.0f);
props.forwardVector = X3DAUDIO_VECTOR(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
props.topVector = X3DAUDIO_VECTOR(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

In my coordinate system x is from right to left, up is z, and y is near to far.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of parameters and steps to properly using X3DAudio, and I can't really tell from the code above if you have properly zero'd and set all the values in `X3DAUDIO_LISTENER`, `X3DAUDIO_EMITTER`, and `X3DAUDIO_DSP_SETTINGS` so check those first. Any uninitialized values will cause problems.

The most recent versions of the XAudio2 samples that originally shipped in the legacy DirectX SDK can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/tree/master/XAudio2). In particular, look at **XAudio2Sound3D**. You should try hard-coding all the emitter/listener values to something trivial to test and make sure that works before hooking it up to your coordinate system.

> In addition to the XAudio2 samples from the legacy DirectX SDK, you should take a look at *DirectX Tool Kit for Audio* which is part of the *DirectX Tool Kit* for [DX11](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK) / [DX12](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12).

Comment: Still sounds mono. Matrix coefficients are equal no matter what I do and the matrix is 2x2. In their code, they use 1x1 matrix for some reason so how does it sound 3D then?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and what I found out is that when building for 64 bit version the second and third value in matrix were calculated flipped for some reason. This does not apply for 1 channel (mono) audio.

after X3DAudioCalculate() function try

```
float f = p3dAudioMatrix [1];
p3dAudioMatrix [1] = p3dAudioMatrix [2];
p3dAudioMatrix [2] = f;
```